# Internal Server Error (trying Yesod Auth-package)

Tags: haskell, yesod

I was following the y-book example of Authorization of a user with a plan to put this into the scaffolding example: show the first page, have there login link, and if login succeeds with browserId, then let the user go to blog.

There is a good example on y-wiki, but I wanted to try this. So, in the Foundation.hs inside "instance Yesod App where"

```
-- route name, then a boolean indicating if it's a write request
isAuthorized HomeR True = isMyAuth
isAuthorized BlogR _ = isMyAuth
-- anyone can access other pages
isAuthorized _ _ = return Authorized
```

After those outside the instance-scope:

```
isMyAuth = do
  mu <- maybeAuthId
  return $ case mu of
    Nothing -> AuthenticationRequired
    Just "mylog" -> Authorized
    Just _ -> Unauthorized "You must be an mylog"
```

And in instance YesodAuthApp where

```
-- type AuthId App = UserId
type AuthId App = Text
```

and also changed loginDest to point to BlogR. How should I write the getAuthId with db-access. I just want to compare it to the very same text "mylog" as in the isMyAuth-function. By commenting getAuthId out, we get the internal server error. Is it possible to prevent ghc to compile if this method is missing?

With

getAuthId creds = return $ Just "mylog"

it seems to compile. However, after "sign in" this stays on the login page does not redirect to BlogR-page.

Comment: Hello, 
what about to define
 
onLogin = redirect BlogR  ?